# How to add notes to a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I really can't seem to figure it out, and of course Facebook help is of... no help at all (as usual).

I manage a bunch of Facebook pages, but never had the necessity to add notes to them; now I have it. So I went to the page settings and enabled the "Notes" applications; and "Notes" actually showed up in the page's menu. But when I click on it, nothing happens: I just go back to my page's wall.

Is this some kind of strange bug or am I missing something?!?

Comment: Are you using facebook as you or as another entity, like a community page? I find that a lot of functionality doesn't work when you switch from being you.

Comment: I'm using it as myself, and I am (of course) the admin of the page; I also tried using it as the page itself, but it doesn't work, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `https://www.facebook.com/notes.php?id=[YOUR_PAGE_ID]`

Or type [Notes](http://www.facebook.com/notes.php?pages) at the top then search on the left for your Page.

Or go to your Page and click "Use Facebook as [PAGE NAME]" then click [Notes](http://www.facebook.com/notes.php?pages)

If none of these work then I would contact [support](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=pages_bug).

Comment: The first one worked, I was able to create a note and now I can succesfully access the "Notes" section via the standard link. Looks like it was some sort of bug...

Answer (score 3):

One thing to note is that you can add the Notes application to the favorites.

1. Switch to "Use Facebook as [my page name]"
2. Search for the Notes application --> it appears on the left menu
3. Move the mouse over it, click on the pen appears to its left, and select "Add to Favorites"

Comment: This must have been chosen as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Go into 'Admin' (settings), and the 'Apps' menu (down left side), then you can select the 'Notes' app to change it's settings etc.